# Issue with metatags and sharing on LinkedIn

Tags: html, http, linkedin-api

Help with meta tags please.
I have set the next :

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ object_post.title }}" >
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ object_post.description }}">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://some_site.com/blog/post/{{ object_post.id }}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://some_site.com{% static "content/blog/images/" %}{{ object_post.id }}.jpg" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" class="meta-article">
```

And them is correctly. I checked on facebook developers site.
But I have an issue and question.

1) Issue - why it still showing not correct title, description and image? But url and type are correct.
2) What is must be the sharing link? I mean if we are using meta tags. Which one must be link on only simple sharing this post?

Thanks

Comment: Hi try sharing a different page on social media that you have not shared yet. F/B caches unfortunately and I would assume linkedin does as well. I ran into this issue before.

Comment: OMG... man you're right :)

Comment: thank you) I have spend so much time on this shit :)

Comment: LOL... yeah I did too back when I first encountered this little goodie :o)

Answer (score 0):

**Formal Answser:** Facebook and LinkedIn cache the cards still as of 05/2017. When making changes be sure to share a page you have not previously shared to see your updated content.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020, LinkedIn appears to be much better at doing caching well.  But there are two well-known ways to force LinkedIn to update the cache...

**Technique 1:** If you are normally sharing `www.example.com`, try sharing `www.example.com?randomItem=huzzah`.  Because the URL is different, it will not have it in cache, though the page will fundamentally behave the same  -- unless you use `randomItem` as a `GET` param.  Make sure that the fake param here is not actually used!

**Technique 2:** Load your site into the **[LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/)**, and check to see how it looks.  Since you are debugging with the inspector, it knows to refresh the cache automatically.

*Hope this helps!*